# Pods in StatefulSet still terminating after the old liveness probe time

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod which takes a long time.

The liveness and readiness probe looked like this:

```yaml
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: api
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 240
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 60
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: api
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Now, the container needs more than 4 minutes to start up. I set `initialDelaySeconds` for the liveness probe to 7200 (two hours) but after applying this, it still stops after four minutes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just going to check the obvious to begin with: Have you checked the logs of the pod to see if it's actually terminating due to something else? Perhaps it's trying to connect to something remote and failing repeatedly, then giving up?

Comment: I completely removed readiness and liveness probes for now, did `kubectl rollout restart` and kubectl delete`d the failing pod, this time it ran through. In the next break when we don't need the pod, I'll re-add the probes with larger timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the same endpoint for the checks and it takes too long, then the readiness probe will time out after 3 failures before it even calls the liveness probe.

Readiness should be used if the container is temporarily unable to service traffic, it will be called periodically and then the container will start to receive traffic if it starts returning successfully.

It is not clear why your pod is taking so long and whether that is just at startup or when running.